# log4j configuration for external jars

Tags: java

I have two maven projects say A and B. A is using B.jar as an external jar. The log4j.properties for A is as below

> ```
> log4j.rootLogger=INFO,file
> log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
> log4j.appender.file.File=/u01/app/log/a.log
> log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
> log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
> log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
> log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
> ```

/u01/app/log directory is a directory in the server where the java application is deployed. Its writing logs from A to the specified file but its not writing logs from B.jar in the file ,when I tried with same properties in B.jar.It seems B is not able to access the directory..please help me to configure properties in B.jar and write logs from  B to the same file a.log

Comment: Add your project configuration for a and b. How is the project constructed?

Answer (score 0):

If they are maven projects, the maven forces you to structure your projects.

You should put your configuration files in the resources

```
Project
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- resources
```

Maven will find them. In your case, you should have two configuration file for project A and B and a configuration file for project A and a configuration file for the project B should be ready in the appropriate places (resources in your case)